# Undefined method `relations` when assigning belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have 2 models:

```
class Annotation
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :event
  field :desc, type: String
end

class Event::Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :annotations
end
```

And then I created 2 objects in rails console by typing:

```
a = Annotation.new
e = Event::Event.new
```

Now everythings is good, but when I do

```
a.event = e
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `relations' for Event:Module
```

Why is this error happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: why is it `class Event::Event`

Comment: @Deepak Because I want to give it a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Annotation
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :event, class_name: 'Event::Event'
  ...
end
```

The `belongs_to` association by default assumes the associated object to be of type `Event`, but `Event` is a module. Class name here should be `Event::Event`. So, that needs to be specified in the relation.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi there you solved my problem! Thank you very much. I did not know that the default would assumes Event. Can you please tell me which part of documentation specify that? Thank you for you help because I am new to Rails. Sorry for asking noob questions.

Comment: No probs. Though i know this option from my daily use of this. Here is the doc that you can go through for more details. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to